# Dual-booting Ubuntu and Pardus with GRUB2...Pardus no show?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, bootloader, grub

I have Ubuntu 10.10 installed and used to dual-boot Fedora, but I replaced Fedora with Pardus.

After the install, I went into ubuntu, and did a sudo update-grub. It detected my Pardus 2011 install there. When I rebooted, it did not show up in my grub2 menu however. I went back to Ubuntu and did it again...then checked the grub.cfg, and it is not there. I have read that Pardus uses a grub legacy.

How can I get Pardus into my grub2 menu?

Thanks!

sudo fdisk -l

```
    Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
    255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders
    Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    Disk identifier: 0xd9b3496e

    Device Boot Start End Blocks Id System
    /dev/sda1 * 1 15197 122067968 83 Linux
    /dev/sda2 36394 60802 196059757 5 Extended
    /dev/sda3 15197 30394 122067968 83 Linux
    /dev/sda5 36394 59434 185075308 7 HPFS/NTFS
    /dev/sda6 59434 60802 10983424 82 Linux swap / Solaris

    Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

and

update-grub

```
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-25-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-25-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Pardus 2011 (2011) on /dev/sda3
```

Yet after this, I go to grub.cfg, and Pardus is not there.

Answer (score 0):

When you installed pardus, you should have made the installer to not to install the bootloader on the MBR and instead do it on the pardus partition? Grub2 will not update be able to boot pardus if you have not done this.

Comment: I didn't install the bootloader for pardus at all.  And if I believe correctly, my bootloader for Ubuntu (Grub2) is installed on the Ubuntu partition.

Answer (score 0):

A bootloader installation is required for each of your Linux installations. But, one of these bootloader programs should be installed on MBR. The MBR on a disk is only 512 in size and the rest of the bootloader is installed on the /boot directory.

So, Pardus and Ubuntu BOTH need to have their bootloader programs installed in their respective /boot directories. Only one of these bootloader programs, either that of Pardus or Ubuntu, needs to be written to the MBR. The other boot loader program should be written directly to the system partition.

You shouldn't choose to not to install the bootloader for Pardus. Install Pardus but choose not to install the bootloader to MBR and instead choose /boot directory. Next boot into Ubuntu and update grub. It will then recognize the Pardus partition and copy its boot entry to grub.cfg.

For basic multiboot info, try this [How To DualBoot or MuliBoot Operating Systems](http://www.vsubhash.com/article.asp?MV-RFM-IE=on&id=24&info=How_To_Dual-Boot_or_Multi-Boot_Operating_Systems).